# pycharm is not showing in app launcher and anywhere in elementary juno

Tags: software-installation, applications, release-juno, elementary-website, thirdpartyapps

I have installed pycharm community in elementary juno but it is not showing in app launcher and anywhere and when i run this `./pycharm.sh` from the extracted file in terminal it run... I can't even uninstall pycharm
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is a menu option in Pycharm to create a shortcut in the App Launcher.

1) Start PyCharm...

```
 sudo ./pycharm.sh
```

...like you mentioned above.

2) Once PyCharm is up and running, go to the **Tools** menu and select **"Create Desktop Entry..."**  I think it also asks you if you want to create the desktop entry for all users.

[image: Pycharm - Create Desktop Entry]

Now the Pycharm program will be in the Application menu.